# How to set a default text to app widget when there is no data?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-appwidget

I am using GridView in my app-widget. I want to set a default text to the app-widget when there is no data. I tried doing using getLoadingView() method but it's not working.

getLoadingViewMethod() of WidgetViewsFactory.java:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {

    Log.e("textview is displayed","true");
    RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_default_display);
    row.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_default_widget,"DEFAULT TEXT");
    return row;
}
```

widget_default_display.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_default_widget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_notifications"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_sub_title_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_title_size"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `RemoteViews#setEmptyView()` method, if I'm following you correctly. You'd call that on the main `RemoteViews` for your widget.

Comment: @MikeM., I read about setEmptyView(). But I am not getting where to call this method exactly?

Comment: In your `AppWidgetProvider`, when you create the `RemoteViews` with the layout that has your `GridView`. You'd call it on that `RemoteViews`. You'll want to move your `txt_default_widget` `TextView` to that layout, too, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `AdapterView` in an App Widget is used very similarly to one in your app's local layout. To display a certain `View` when the `AdapterView`'s collection is empty, you need to set that `View` as the empty `View` on the `AdapterView`.

For a Widget, the `RemoteViews` class has the `setEmptyView()` method for this. You'd use this method in your `AppWidgetProvider`, after creating the main `RemoteViews` object from the layout that contains your `GridView`. For example:

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
...

rv.setEmptyView(R.id.grid_view, R.id.txt_default_widget);
```

Please note that the empty `View` - the `txt_default_widget` `TextView`, in this case - must be in the same main layout as the `GridView`, rather than in the item layout.

Answer (score 0):

You may set empty view for your adapter.

```
View emptyView = LayoutInflater.from(yourContext).inflate(R.layout.xml_for_empty_view, null, false);
yourAdapter.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```